# Record animation of canvas with a long time

Tags: javascript, canvas, recording, media-source

I have to record animation from canvas and the animation takes about 2 minutes.
I'm using `MediaRecorder` and canvas `captureStream` to record the canvas, everything works well, but we have to wait for 2 minutes of capturing.

Is there any solution to improve the time of recording?

---

Currently, my solution is to separate the animation into small parts, then using MediaSource to contact the blob data, but I can not download the MediaSource.

Comment: To be clear, your idea was to run multiple renderers in parallel, record each of these renderers and concat the resulting chunks in a single video?

Comment: Yes, it's my idea, but I still meet the problem with contact the blob of data. and I curious if we have other approaches?